# Have a class of inputs, and need to know what input has been changed, after it has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class of inputs. I want to be able to detect what specific input has changed. I am first detecting a change in the class, and then I want to know what input has changed.

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="className"/>
<script>
$('.className').keyup(function(){
  //Want to say 'You changed '(the id of the input changed)'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.id` to get the `id` of current element.

```js
$('.className').keyup(function(){
  console.log('You changed '+this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="className"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

All DOM event handlers are automatically passed a reference to the `Event` object that represents the event that triggered the function. You can use this object's `.target` property to access the DOM object responsible for triggering the event.

You can also use `this` in place of `event.target`, but this will only be accurate if you are not utilizing event delegation (bubbling).

```js
$('.className').keyup(function(event){
  console.log("The instigator was: " + event.target.toString() + " with an id of: " + event.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="className"/>
```